# ImageView setImageURI is causing strictmode error onPause

Tags: android, imageview, android-strictmode

Every time I finish an application that contains a GridView with an ArrayAdapter in which I return an ImageView from getView() I get an error that says:

> 01-15 17:28:55.715: E/StrictMode(6480): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks. E/StrictMode(6480):
>   java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called

The problem appears to point to several lines with:

`imageView.setImageURI(uri)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In certain situations setImageURI() opens an InputStream but doesn't close it. Here is a workaround:

```
InputStream is = null;
try { 
  if(uri != null) {
    is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
  }
} catch(Exception e) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Unable to set ImageView from URI: " + e.toString());
} finally {
  org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
}
```

Comment: Thanks richardleggett - worked perfectly (after weeks of having the issue and not being able to find the cause!)